# Rails 3: After_save create profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user model and a profile model that are tied together.

What I'd like to do is to create an user profile every time an user registers.

Here's what I have in the User model now:

```
 after_save :create_profile

  protected

  def create_profile
    @profile = current_user.build_profile(params[:profile])
    @profile.save
  end
```

However, it doesn't seem to work because current_user is not recognized, which makes sense, however, what's the way to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.profile.create(params[:profile])
```

Answer (score 0):

For a has_one association:

> self.create_profile(params[:profile])

has_many

> self.profiles.create(params[:profile])